# Express a predicate DATE >= X and DATE < Y in form of DATE in [X,Y)

Tags: postgresql

As per this paper:

[image]

I can express an upper and lower bound as a single predicate.

- How can I do it in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [date range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)

```
daterange(x, y, '[)') @> the_date
```

The `@>` operator tests if the value on the right hand side is contained in the range on the left hand side

Comment: Let me mention that the speed-up quoted in the question probably won't happen in PostgreSQL. You'd need a GiST index, but I doubt that the speed will be much different from the original query with a B-tree index.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: ah, right. I didn't see the part about performance improvement. Yes, that won't make things faster.